# Get data attr value on hover

Tags: javascript

I have a few links. When I hover mouse over the links I would like to get the values stored in data attributes. I need to pick the t values and pass them into function

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-lat="23.333452" data-lon="-97.2234234">
```

**JS**

```
var loc = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-lat]");
                                
loc.addEventListener("mouseover", locOver);
loc.addEventListener("mouseout", locOut);

function locOver() {
   // do something
}

function locOut() {
   // do something else
}
```

It's been a while since I used vanilla JS and it's been a long day so I'm sure it's pretty close but I'm stuck. I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: loc.addEventListener is not a function

What am I missing here?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList which doesn't have a `addEventListener()` method. You need to loop through the elements in the NodeList, and then use `addEventListener()` on each element. If you only have one anchor tag with a `data-lat`, then you can change `.querySelectorAll()` to just `.querySelector()` to get an element instead of a NodeList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the nodes that you obtained with `document.querySelectorAll("a[data-lat]")` for adding events.

Working example.

```html
<a href="#" data-lat="23.333452" data-lon="-97.2234234">Node</a>
<script>
    var loc = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-lat]");

    loc.forEach(node => {
        node.addEventListener("mouseover", locOver);
        node.addEventListener("mouseout", locOut);
    })


    function locOver(event) {
        // do something
        console.log('mouseover', event.target.dataset)
    }

    function locOut() {
        // do something
        console.log('locOut')
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const loc = document.querySelector("a[data-lat]");

const locOver = () => {
   console.log("Mouse is over the link");
}

const locOut = () => {
   console.log("Mouse is out of the link");
}
                                
loc.addEventListener("mouseover", locOver);
loc.addEventListener("mouseout", locOut);
```

```html
<a href="#" data-lat="23.333452" data-lon="-97.2234234">Link</a>
```

Explanation:
I target the link using .querySelector method that returns a single node.
After that i created two event handler for mouseOver and mouseOut and than i added the eventListener to the link.